Linux OOM with Docker and tons of swap memory available
My server is killing MariaDB periodically due to Out of Memory. The thing is, there's tons of swap memory available, and the swapiness is set to 100. One way or another, from the kernel dump, nothing indicates any kind of huge memory use. MariaDB is running inside a Docker container. What may be happening here? How can I further debug this?
Note: I removed most of the processes from the dump below. MariaDB was by far the one consuming most memory.
kernel: [9484097.392673] Purging GPU memory, 0 pages freed, 0 pages still pinned, 1 pages left available.
kernel: [9484097.392877] bash invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x40cc0(GFP_KERNEL|__GFP_COMP), order=3, oom_score_adj=0
kernel: [9484097.392881] CPU: 4 PID: 2030589 Comm: bash Tainted: P            E     5.11.0-27-generic #29~20.04.1-Ubuntu
kernel: [9484097.392884] Hardware name: Dell Inc. OptiPlex 5090/0FXD80, BIOS 1.1.51 08/26/2021
kernel: [9484097.392885] Call Trace:
kernel: [9484097.392887]  dump_stack+0x74/0x92
kernel: [9484097.392891]  dump_header+0x4f/0x1f6
kernel: [9484097.392894]  oom_kill_process.cold+0xb/0x10
kernel: [9484097.392897]  out_of_memory.part.0+0x1ee/0x460
kernel: [9484097.392900]  out_of_memory+0x6d/0xd0
kernel: [9484097.392902]  __alloc_pages_slowpath.constprop.0+0xc4d/0xd20
kernel: [9484097.392905]  __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x2a0/0x300
kernel: [9484097.392907]  alloc_pages_current+0x87/0xe0
kernel: [9484097.392910]  kmalloc_order+0x2d/0xa0
kernel: [9484097.392913]  kmalloc_order_trace+0x1d/0x80
kernel: [9484097.392915]  __kmalloc+0x3f3/0x470
kernel: [9484097.392919]  0xffffffffc0e2a362
kernel: [9484097.392925]  cshook_systemcalltable_pre_compat_sys_ioctl+0x2e6c0/0x37310 [falcon_lsm_serviceable]
kernel: [9484097.392930]  cshook_network_ops_inet6_sockraw_release+0x1ce48/0x208a0 [falcon_lsm_serviceable]
kernel: [9484097.392933]  ? cshook_security_inode_free_security+0x73d8/0x9a10 [falcon_lsm_serviceable]
kernel: [9484097.392936]  cshook_network_ops_inet6_sockraw_release+0x1de32/0x208a0 [falcon_lsm_serviceable]
kernel: [9484097.392940]  ? LoadImageEventSource_GetImageHashMem+0x4bf5/0x8ab0 [falcon_lsm_serviceable]
kernel: [9484097.392944]  cshook_network_ops_inet6_sockraw_release+0x1dfe5/0x208a0 [falcon_lsm_serviceable]
kernel: [9484097.392947]  _ZdlPv+0x3bd26/0x4fd50 [falcon_lsm_serviceable]
kernel: [9484097.392949]  ? _ZdlPv+0x3bb40/0x4fd50 [falcon_lsm_serviceable]
kernel: [9484097.392952]  _ZdlPv+0x3c5de/0x4fd50 [falcon_lsm_serviceable]
kernel: [9484097.392955]  _ZdlPv+0x3c669/0x4fd50 [falcon_lsm_serviceable]
kernel: [9484097.392957]  cshook_systemcalltable_pre_compat_sys_ioctl+0x21582/0x37310 [falcon_lsm_serviceable]
kernel: [9484097.392960]  ? 0xffffffffc0e2b56e
kernel: [9484097.392964]  cshook_security_sb_free_security+0x3f93/0x4540 [falcon_lsm_serviceable]
kernel: [9484097.392968]  cshook_security_sb_free_security+0x3135/0x4540 [falcon_lsm_serviceable]
kernel: [9484097.392973]  cshook_security_sb_free_security+0x3950/0x4540 [falcon_lsm_serviceable]
kernel: [9484097.392977]  cshook_security_file_permission+0x8ca/0x1060 [falcon_lsm_serviceable]
kernel: [9484097.392981]  ? 0xffffffffc0e2a362
kernel: [9484097.392985]  ? cshook_systemcalltable_pre_compat_sys_ioctl+0x2e6f4/0x37310 [falcon_lsm_serviceable]
kernel: [9484097.392988]  cshook_security_file_permission+0xde7/0x1060 [falcon_lsm_serviceable]
kernel: [9484097.392992]  cshook_security_bprm_check_security+0x69/0xe0 [falcon_lsm_serviceable]
kernel: [9484097.392996]  pinnedhook_security_bprm_check_security+0x3c/0x70 [falcon_lsm_pinned_16206]
kernel: [9484097.393001]  security_bprm_check+0x27/0x40
kernel: [9484097.393004]  exec_binprm+0xe7/0x420
kernel: [9484097.393006]  bprm_execve+0x16d/0x290
kernel: [9484097.393008]  do_execveat_common.isra.0+0x189/0x1c0
kernel: [9484097.393011]  __x64_sys_execve+0x37/0x50
kernel: [9484097.393013]  do_syscall_64+0x38/0x90
kernel: [9484097.393016]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
kernel: [9484097.393018] RIP: 0033:0x7f511d5da0fb
kernel: [9484097.393020] Code: f8 01 0f 8e bd fe ff ff 5b 48 8d 3d df 59 13 00 5d 41 5c e9 97 62 fa ff 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa b8 3b 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d 05 dd 12 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
kernel: [9484097.393022] RSP: 002b:00007ffc5e6504e8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 000000000000003b
kernel: [9484097.393024] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000558b0590aff0 RCX: 00007f511d5da0fb
kernel: [9484097.393025] RDX: 0000558b060bd670 RSI: 0000558b060be660 RDI: 0000558b060bd540
kernel: [9484097.393026] RBP: 0000558b060bd540 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000558b060be660
kernel: [9484097.393027] R10: 00007f511d708d10 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000558b060bd540
kernel: [9484097.393028] R13: 0000558b060be660 R14: 0000558b060bd670 R15: 0000558b0590af3c
kernel: [9484097.393030] Mem-Info:
kernel: [9484097.393032] active_anon:32657 inactive_anon:388766 isolated_anon:0
kernel: [9484097.393032]  active_file:236257 inactive_file:954342 isolated_file:0
kernel: [9484097.393032]  unevictable:4660 dirty:2311 writeback:0
kernel: [9484097.393032]  slab_reclaimable:183875 slab_unreclaimable:75067
kernel: [9484097.393032]  mapped:86112 shmem:2143 pagetables:12640 bounce:0
kernel: [9484097.393032]  free:42867 free_pcp:376 free_cma:0
kernel: [9484097.393036] Node 0 active_anon:130628kB inactive_anon:1555064kB active_file:945028kB inactive_file:3817368kB unevictable:18640kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB mapped:344448kB dirty:9244kB writeback:0kB shmem:8572kB shmem_thp: 0kB shmem_pmdmapped: 0kB anon_thp: 0kB writeback_tmp:0kB kernel_stack:40928kB pagetables:50560kB all_unreclaimable? no
kernel: [9484097.393039] Node 0 DMA free:14884kB min:136kB low:168kB high:200kB reserved_highatomic:0KB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:15992kB managed:15908kB mlocked:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
kernel: [9484097.393042] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 1402 7587 7587 7587
kernel: [9484097.393045] Node 0 DMA32 free:72236kB min:12468kB low:15584kB high:18700kB reserved_highatomic:0KB active_anon:11312kB inactive_anon:337820kB active_file:155040kB inactive_file:673224kB unevictable:48kB writepending:588kB present:1589708kB managed:1523848kB mlocked:48kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:1052kB local_pcp:40kB free_cma:0kB
kernel: [9484097.393049] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 6184 6184 6184
kernel: [9484097.393052] Node 0 Normal free:84348kB min:54976kB low:68720kB high:82464kB reserved_highatomic:2048KB active_anon:119316kB inactive_anon:1216372kB active_file:789988kB inactive_file:3145876kB unevictable:18592kB writepending:8656kB present:6512640kB managed:6340644kB mlocked:18476kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:452kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
kernel: [9484097.393055] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
kernel: [9484097.393058] Node 0 DMA: 3*4kB (U) 1*8kB (U) 1*16kB (U) 0*32kB 2*64kB (U) 1*128kB (U) 1*256kB (U) 0*512kB 0*1024kB 1*2048kB (M) 3*4096kB (M) = 14884kB
kernel: [9484097.393068] Node 0 DMA32: 6103*4kB (UE) 1997*8kB (UE) 2008*16kB (UE) 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 72516kB
kernel: [9484097.393076] Node 0 Normal: 5120*4kB (UEH) 2433*8kB (UEH) 2892*16kB (UEH) 1*32kB (H) 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 86248kB
kernel: [9484097.393085] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
kernel: [9484097.393087] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
kernel: [9484097.393088] 1217872 total pagecache pages
kernel: [9484097.393089] 23192 pages in swap cache
kernel: [9484097.393090] Swap cache stats: add 3011895, delete 2988503, find 103821394/104463504
kernel: [9484097.393091] Free swap  = 3874508kB
kernel: [9484097.393092] Total swap = 4194300kB
kernel: [9484097.393092] 2029585 pages RAM
kernel: [9484097.393093] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
kernel: [9484097.393093] 59485 pages reserved
kernel: [9484097.393094] 0 pages hwpoisoned
kernel: [9484097.393094] Tasks state (memory values in pages):
kernel: [9484097.393095] [  pid  ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name
kernel: [9484097.393111] [    687]     0   687      698        0    45056       30             0 falcond
kernel: [9484097.393113] [    688]     0   688   505660     5971   327680     1633             0 falcon-sensor
kernel: [9484097.393137] [    855]     0   855   541254     4791   421888     1144          -999 containerd
kernel: [9484097.393146] [   1283]     0  1283   749675    11418   655360     1711          -500 dockerd
kernel: [9484097.393215] [ 360705]   999 360705  1707021    70258  1396736       21             0 mariadbd
kernel: [9484097.393940] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=2a8e9308e3efb49deadde95237efaeb3f2fc3421ad65a3a5b18750d8d8f7deb5,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/docker/99fa2d54134f8e550f363b25927323e7711008dda5da43cbb16a7ec9df2802c1,task=mariadbd,pid=360705,uid=999
kernel: [9484097.394218] Out of memory: Killed process 360705 (mariadbd) total-vm:6828084kB, anon-rss:259524kB, file-rss:21508kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:999 pgtables:1364kB oom_score_adj:0
kernel: [9484097.407371] oom_reaper: reaped process 360705 (mariadbd), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB

EDIT: Adding info about the system as per request
H/W path             Device       Class          Description
============================================================
                                  system         OptiPlex 7050 (07A1)
/0                                bus            0NW6H5
/0/0                              memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/9                              memory         8GiB System Memory
/0/9/0                            memory         4GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
/0/9/1                            memory         4GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
/0/9/2                            memory         [empty]
/0/9/3                            memory         [empty]
/0/f                              memory         256KiB L1 cache
/0/10                             memory         1MiB L2 cache
/0/11                             memory         8MiB L3 cache
/0/12                             processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz
/0/100                            bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
/0/100/2                          display        HD Graphics 630
/0/100/14                         bus            200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
/0/100/14/0          usb1         bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/3                     bus            Hub
/0/100/14/0/3/1                   multimedia     USB PnP Audio Device
/0/100/14/0/3/2                   multimedia     USB PnP Audio Device
/0/100/14/0/3/3                   multimedia     USB PnP Audio Device
/0/100/14/0/3/4                   multimedia     USB PnP Audio Device
/0/100/14/0/3/5                   bus            Hub
/0/100/14/0/3/5/1                 multimedia     USB PnP Audio Device
/0/100/14/0/3/5/2                 multimedia     USB PnP Audio Device
/0/100/14/0/3/5/3                 multimedia     USB PnP Audio Device
/0/100/14/0/3/5/4                 multimedia     USB PnP Audio Device
/0/100/14/0/3/5/5                 bus            Hub
/0/100/14/0/3/5/5/1               multimedia     USB PnP Audio Device
/0/100/14/0/3/5/5/2               multimedia     USB PnP Audio Device
/0/100/14/0/3/5/5/3               multimedia     USB PnP Audio Device
/0/100/14/0/3/5/5/4               multimedia     USB PnP Audio Device
/0/100/14/0/3/5/5/5               generic        FT232R USB UART
/0/100/14/0/3/5/5/6               multimedia     USB PnP Audio Device
/0/100/14/0/3/5/5/7               multimedia     USB PnP Audio Device
/0/100/14/0/3/5/6                 multimedia     USB PnP Audio Device
/0/100/14/0/3/5/7                 multimedia     USB PnP Audio Device
/0/100/14/1          usb2         bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14.2                       generic        200 Series PCH Thermal Subsystem
/0/100/15                         generic        200 Series PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0
/0/100/16                         communication  200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1
/0/100/17                         storage        SATA Controller [RAID mode]
/0/100/1d                         bridge         200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #9
/0/100/1f                         bridge         200 Series PCH LPC Controller (Q270)
/0/100/1f.2                       memory         Memory controller
/0/100/1f.4                       bus            200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
/0/100/1f.6          eth0         network        Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM
/0/1                              system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/2                              communication  PnP device PNP0501
/0/3                              input          PnP device PNP0303
/0/4                              input          PnP device PNP0f03
/0/5                              system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/6                              system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/7                              system         PnP device PNP0b00
/0/8                              generic        PnP device INT3f0d
/0/a                              system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/b                              system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/c                              system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/d                              system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/e                 scsi0        storage        
/0/e/0.0.0           /dev/sda     disk           1TB ST1000DM010-2EP1
/0/e/0.0.0/1         /dev/sda1    volume         511MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/e/0.0.0/2         /dev/sda2    volume         931GiB EXT4 volume
/0/13                scsi1        storage        
/0/13/0.0.0          /dev/cdrom   disk           DVD+-RW DU-8A5LH
/1                   veth2e771c6  network        Ethernet interface
/2                   veth7cb2db4  network        Ethernet interface
/3                   vethf37e821  network        Ethernet interface
/4                   vethd70ba99  network        Ethernet interface
/5                   veth2bcd630  network        Ethernet interface
/6                   vethd242ecd  network        Ethernet interface
/7                   veth7ed6a4b  network        Ethernet interface

.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu-Server 20.04.3 2021.09.15 customized using Cubic on 2021-09-15 14:33
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal


don't use swap, add ram

@djdomi this is not an option, and one way or another is this even the root of the problem here?

If you had enough ram, the OOM killer would not become active.

hei, we know nothing about the system, please show them us

@GeraldSchneider What about swap memory? Shouldn't the system try to use the almost 4GB I have available?

@djdomi I edited in some info, thanks for taking a look at it

No, not at all, swap should never considered as "active" RAM. Why is adding RAM on a Business Device not an option? Wait a second i really see that you use an OptiPlex 7050 as a server? Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault. And moreover, there are 2 Banks left by the way

OptiPlex 5090, and moreover, within Docker, so we don't know what else there could be running on the computer. Since that's a container, maybe, you allocated too little memory to it? Probably no swap or too little swap is allocated to the container, that's why it's not using swap and kills processes instead? Run cat /proc/meminfo within docker exec to that container while it's running, and see how much swap and memory the container sees.


Swap is extremely slow, not for regular use as a substitute for RAM
Swap cannot be used as memory extension. Swapped out memory cannot simply be accessed. It has to be swapped back into RAM before accessing. Likewise, a particular allocated memory block has to fit fully in RAM. Swap is just a way to dump some RAM to file to later retrieve back to RAM if needed. MariaDB is a DB. It needs its pages. Swap is not an option, you will OOM.
With little memory left you will suffer more fragmentation issues allowing you to OOM easily. Get more RAM.

Edit to address the comment in question stating this is incorrect (adding details): Swap on Linux is designed to offload occupied areas of RAM which are not being accessed to disk. This Memory cannot be accessed directly from swap. Trying to access a memory which has been swapped out results in a page fault being raised. This interrupt then puts that memory back in RAM prior to access. Swap is therefore not an extension of RAM as it doesn’t behave like RAM nor can it be accessed as such (well the applications don’t know that, but Linux internally does). For a page fault to succeed, you need enough RAM to read the swapped out memory back into. MariaDB will do large allocations which it tries to access for its indexes. If there isn’t enough RAM to read swap pages into for MariaDB to work, you are out of RAM, and swap won’t help.

Swap is literally designed to be a memory extension. There can be swap on a different back end devices; ex. the ramdisk shared over Infiniband is registered on the "acceptor" node as a swap device, and that swap is very fast, faster than many SSDs out there. The answer is wrong and doesn't address the particular issue in the question.

Swap on Linux is designed to offload occupied areas of RAM which are not being accessed to disk. This Memory cannot be accessed directly from swap. Trying to access a memory which has been swapped out results in a page fault being raised. This interrupt then puts that memory back in RAM prior to access. Swap is therefore not an extension of RAM as it doesn’t behave like RAM nor can it be accessed as such. For a page fault to succeed, you need enough RAM to read the swapped out memory back into. This answer does address the question. You need more RAM, swap is not a substitute.

You shouldn't tell me how the page fault based swap works in x86; I know that mechanism for at least 25 years. (And that's not an "interrupt", by the way; Intel manuals call this thing an exception of type fault. True interrupt is an event that originates outside of the processor.) Not everybody knows about the technique of extending the memory of one computer by attaching the memory of other computer as a swap, which is stored on a ram disk connected via Infiniband. It's very fast, 1.5 times slower than local memory, still it's a swap.

Also, the answer doesn't explain the question: why there is OOM while plenty of a swap available? You hadn't touched this main subject, which is the title.

You are quite rude. And wrong. A page fault while not an interrupt itself, will cause an interrupt. This is how Linux handles such faults. Interrupts don’t need to originate outside the CPU either. There are timer interrupts that are triggered by the CPU after a time expires for example. And since we agree on the fact that a page fault must happen before swapped out pages can be swapped back in and accessed, let’s leave it at that. Even with Infiniband, page faults must happen and memory must be accessed once it’s been paged in. It’s literally how it connects to the CPU via the motherboard.

Ok I checked, and yes. Even with Infiniband and swap memory extension, the machine which has its memory extended (for lack of better wording), still needs to page fault and move stuff to RAM. This is no different. It’s slow because of the sheer number of page faults this needs to cause. Moreover, if you have 4GB of actual RAM available and even 100GB of SWAP free, trying to perform a single 5GB allocation will cause an OOM, as expected. The original poster most likely simply needs more RAM as indexes must be paged in. How big the allocations are will depend on how MariaDB is used.
